# Latex borders are drawn too far on table

Tags: latex

I have no clue why, but the borders seem to be drawn too far? What I mean is the top of the borders and maybe some other spots in the header and maybe footer are too long/bleed over where they should (see image below).

Weird borders:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[includefoot,margin=0.30in,headsep=0.0in,bottom=2.3in,footskip=0.125in]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\definecolor{tamu}{HTML}{500000}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{e9e7e8}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\fancyhead[C]{

    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{| l | X | l |}[rules/color=tamu,rules/width=1mm]
    \CodeBefore
        \rowlistcolors{1}{red!15}
    \Body
    
    \toprule[1mm]
    Experiment Number       &       Experiment      &   Date                            \\[5pt]
                            &                       & \qquad  / \qquad  / \qquad\qquad\qquad  \\[5pt]
    \midrule[1mm]
    Name                    &       Lab Partners    &   CRN                             \\[5pt]
                            &                       &   \\[5pt]
    \bottomrule[1mm]
    \end{NiceTabularX}

}

\fancyfoot[c]{

    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}[rules/color=tamu,rules/width=1mm]
    \CodeBefore
        \rowlistcolors{1}{red!15}
    \Body
    
    \midrule[1mm]
    Signature               & Date                              & TA                & Date          \\[6pt]
                            &\qquad\qquad  / \qquad\qquad  / \qquad\qquad   &                   & \qquad\qquad  / \qquad\qquad  / \qquad\qquad \\[5pt]
    \bottomrule[1mm]
    \end{NiceTabularX}

}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,fit to height=\textheight,colframe=tamu,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=1mm]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Here's the full output for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm the author of `nicematrix`).

The explanation of the phenomenon you see is a little tricky.

We can say that there are two kinds of rules:

- Those drawn by the primitives of TeX `\hrule` and `\vrule`. The command `\hline` of LaTeX and the commands `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` of `booktabs` use internally those rules.
- The rules drawn by PGF/Tikz. In some ways, those rules are not drawn by using a TeX primitive (except `\special`) but are drawn directly in the PDF file with the syntax of PDF. The package `nicematrix` draw its rules with PGF/Tikz.

In the resulting PDF, both kinds of rules are not described exactly with the same syntax. Therefore, the PDF viewers have sometimes some difficulties, and you see the artifact of your question.

In your example, if you use `\Hline` instead of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, you will have a perfect output.

[image: Output of the above code]

Of course, you have not the vertical space added by `\toprule` of `booktabs` but it's possible to use the key `cell-space-top-limit` provided by `nicematrix` to adjust the vertical space between the rule and the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the problem by using the `tabularray` package instead of `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage[includefoot,margin=0.30in,headsep=0.0in,bottom=2.3in,footskip=0.125in]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\definecolor{tamu}{HTML}{500000}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{e9e7e8}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\fancyhead[C]{    
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={Q[l,valign=t]XQ[2.7cm]},
      cells={red!15},
      hlines = {1mm,tamu},
      vlines = {1mm,tamu},
    }
    Experiment Number       &       Experiment      &   Date \par \mbox{}\qquad  / \qquad  / \hfill   \par    \mbox{}                  \\
    Name                    &       Lab Partners    &   CRN  \par  \mbox{}    \par \mbox{}                    \\
    \end{tblr}

}



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,fit to height=\textheight,colframe=tamu,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=1mm]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're amazing, thanks again :)

I did have one question however, Could you explain what `Date \par \mbox{}\qquad  / \qquad  / \hfill   \par    \mbox{}` and `CRN  \par  \mbox{}    \par \mbox{}` do, I am not use to seeing `\par`, `mbox{}`, and `\hfill`. Also how do you find what packages exist/which packages to use? I havent heard of `tblr` before and since I'm relatively new to latex it would be nice to know how to better use packages and find them. Thank you again :)

Comment: @BrightonSikarskie You're welcome! The `\par \mbox{}` bits are a quick hack to add new lines to the cells. While tabularray does have a build in way to specify the height of the rows, the vertical alignment of the text was a bit different than in your example, so I'm using this hack instead. How to find packages? Experience, following the announcements on ctan https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann to see what's new and https://github.com/samcarter/PackageOfTheDay might also be interesting.